# Detect Inputs from Groovy script in Camunda

Tags: groovy, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to find the inputs required to evaluate the groovy expression written inside the decision block (not decision table) in Camunda.

For example :

```
def value;
variableContext.currentsection.extendedAttributes.findAll({
    itr ->
        if (itr.name.equals("creditScore")) {
            value = itr.value
        }
    }
)
creditScore=value;
```

I can see Currentsection inside it we have extendedAttributes which is 'List' and we have name fields.
is there way to fetch these info in camunda ?

- currentsection - object
- extendedAttributes - List
- name - string.